# Cross-platform way to shutdown the computer

Tags: c++, operating-system

I'd like to implement a cross-plaftorm function to shut down the computer without using any system specific API, but the "stdlib.h" std::system function. I have hardly found any reliable resource on the web about it.

On Windows systems the following does the job:

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__)
std::system("shutdown -s -t 0");
#endif
```

What should be the command on other operating systems (like Linux, Mac OSX, etc..)?

Comment: There is no platform independent way, how to shut down asystem is inherently system dependent.

Comment: This is more of an admin than a programming question. The question you are asking is "what is the command line I need to use to shutdown a Linux/MacOSX/... box?" The only relationship with programming is that instead of typing that into a terminal you wrote a program that will call `system` with the arguments

Comment: Design nitpick, personally I'd be a bit miffed (to put it mildly) if some application (other than long-running apps like e.g. video encoding) would shut down the computer. Make sure that is *really* appropriate, and optional.

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree. I want this as an option to shut down the computer after a long-running operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your *nix systems the following should work.

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main() 
{
  system("shutdown -P now");
  return 0;
}
```

However, the above code assumes that you are logged in as the root and if you are not you will get an error while not being logged in as root.

There is no "cross platform" way of doing this except to use a switch statement or if - else statement series for correct syntax of the specified OS.

Comment: yes it should work on OSX I did test it on leopard. At it's core OSX is just Darwin but they don't like to admit that. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/KernelProgramming.pdf Will give you further documentation. Short answer it should work for newer implementations i.e. Mavericks, Yosemite, etc. Also you should know many people are performing this using apple script. But the most straight forward way is C++, with a conditional block to evaluate type of OS.

Answer (score 2):

There is no cross platform shutdown command.

You need to take a look at the shutdown command in the OS you want to have it and then check what OS the client is running and depending on that you can select the right command or code to shut down the specific system.